# How do I add a custom taxonomy as an option for menus under "Appearance" > "Menus"

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom taxonomy and I want to add it as an option for custom menus (under Appearance > Menus). How do I get it to show up there (see the illustration, I want it to show up where the red square is).

[image]

Comment: Check "Screen options" on the "Menu" page. That worked for me. Its true!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your custom taxonomy should show up as an option for custom menus, if you have

```
'show_in_nav_menus' => true
```

as a parameter when you register your post type with `register_post_type()`. You can check all the available parameters in the codex entry http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Comment: I already have "public" set to true, which show_in_nav_menus is supposed to inherit from. However, when I explicitly add the show_in_nav_menus variable and set it to true, it only shows up for the user with the username "Admin". None of the other users can see it there, even ones marked as being an "Administrator"...

Answer (score 38):

Check "Screen options" on the "Menu" page. That worked for me.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now :-D